# How to auto-start WCF service without AppFabric

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

Does anyone know if it is possible to setup a WCF service running on IIS 7.5 so it would start automatically (and not waiting for the first request to come in), **without** the installation of AppFabric?

Comment: hi, do you find a solution? I meet this problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the module IIS 8.0 Application Initialization, which is compatible with IIS 7.5:

[IIS 8.0 Application Initialization](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

Here's the download link for IIS 7.5: [Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization)

An alternative would be to write a small app which calls your service, you could then schedule that to run regularly or when your app pool is recycled.